# How to group in a string a list of objects by different properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of hundred of objects in Javascript, objects look like this :

```
object1 = { objectClass : Car, parentClass : Vehicle, name : BMW }
object2 = { objectClass : Bicycle, parentClass : Vehicle, name : Giant }
object3 = { objectClass : Truck, parentClass : Vehicle, name : VW }
object4 = { objectClass : Country, parentClass : Europe, name : Germany }
object5 = { objectClass : Tradition, parentClass : Europe, name : Hats}
```

I want to group in a big string or an array of strings all objects based on "parentClass" property and display the "name" property of them, based on the above example the string/strings should look like this :

```
Vehicle : BMW, GIANT, VW
Europe : Germany, Hats
```

What would be a good solution for this in Javascript ? Thanks very much in advance !

Comment: What you post isn't an array. It is a bunch of objects.

Comment: Good solutions start with you trying something yourself, thanks very much in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: You could try using ```Array.map()``` followed by ```Array.join()```.

Comment: Sorry, just joined and don't know all the rules, will remind this in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
objectAll = [ object1, object2, object3, object4, object5 ];
const parentList = objectAll.map(val => val.parentClass).filter((val, index, self) => (self.indexOf(val) == index));
const result = parentList.map(val =>  val + ": " + objectAll.filter(value => value.parentClass == val).map(value => value.name).join(','));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ended up using you code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Say if you have an `Array` of the given objects (as it is the best option here), you can iterate through the elements and run a simple `if - else if` block and categorize the values as per need by pushing them into two different arrays, it would look something like this

```js
const objs = [
    { objectClass : 'Car', parentClass : 'Vehicle', name : 'BMW' },
    { objectClass : 'Bicycle', parentClass : 'Vehicle', name : 'Giant' }
] // so on, add as many objects as you want to

// arrays for categorization
const Vehicle = [];
const Europe = [];

// iterating through the array
objs.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.parentClass === 'Vehicle') Vehicle.push(obj.name);
    else if (obj.parentClass === 'Europe') Europe.push(obj.name);
});

// displaying results
console.log(Vehicle.length !== 0 ? `Vehicle: ${Vehicle.join(', ')}` : `Vehicle: none`);
console.log(Europe.length !== 0 ? `Europe: ${Europe.join(', ')}` : `Europe: none`);
```

Comment: Not a big fan of that solution. What if there are more *parentClass groups*?

Comment: Yes, there are hundred of parentClasses

Answer (score 0):

I think [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is a great method you can use here if you first merge all your objects into an array.

```js
const data = [{ objectClass: "Car", parentClass: "Vehicle", name: "BMW" }, { objectClass: "Bicycle", parentClass: "Vehicle", name: "Giant" }, { objectClass: "Truck", parentClass: "Vehicle", name: "VW" }, { objectClass: "Country", parentClass: "Europe", name: "Germany" }, { objectClass: "Tradition", parentClass: "Europe", name: "Hats" }];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
  curr.parentClass in acc ?
  {
    ...acc,
    [curr.parentClass]: [...acc[curr.parentClass], curr.name]
  } :
  {
    ...acc,
    [curr.parentClass]: [curr.name]
  }, {}
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, works very well, wish we could give more accepted answers